# What RederictUrl should one use with ADAL in a Cordova app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8.1, adal, devextreme

I am trying to set up a hybrid Cordova app (AngularJS, DevExtreme) with Azure Active Domain authentication.

For this to work I am using the [Azure Active Directory library for Cordova provided by Microsoft](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova). Here I follow the procedure described in the following snippet:

```js
var AuthenticationContext = Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext;

AuthenticationContext.createAsync(authority)
.then(function (authContext) {
    authContext.acquireTokenAsync(resourceUrl, appId, redirectUrl)
    .then(function (authResponse) {
        console.log("Token acquired: " + authResponse.accessToken);
        console.log("Token will expire on: " + authResponse.expiresOn);
    }, fail);
}, fail);
```

And I got this working within the Android emulator, however for my Windows Phone build it fails. This is probably because I misconfigured the RedirectUrl passed into acquireTokenAsync. What should normally be passed in as the redirect url for a non-hosted Windows Phone (windows store) Cordova app? The app is not hosted on a server but should run locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules are the same as the ones shown in https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-windows-store. Also, please see the release notes in https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova

Comment: The url can be made up like `http://appname` and had to be registered as a redirect url in Azure AD.

Comment: Although in that case you lose the SSO features and the ability to authenticate on the intranet